# Is there spring tension on this garage door part?

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

We have bedrooms above the garage and I am trying to reduce the noise from the garage doors. I have installed a vibration isolation kit like this on the opener/motor, which already made a huge improvement. But I can still hear some noise from the door running in the track.

[image: VIBRATION ISOLATION KIT]

I was thinking of installing another set of these rubber dampers in between the track and the ceiling bracket, but I noticed that the screws holding the bracket on are orange, which, according to Google means that they are under tension. But I can't figure out how there could be tension on this part, since the spring is attached somewhere else completely, and the cable is attached to the bottom of the door.

Is there really tension here? If so, is there a way to install these in this spot without having to unwind the springs?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I not sure you should read too much into the color of the screws. 99% of installed screws are under tension, but very few of them are colored any particular color.

Comment: Would try greasing the bottom of track were the rollers run.  The track is in a precise location, adding those rubber bolts, will need to adjust hanger back same amount.  A 1/2 inch added between track and hanger, need hanger moved back a 1/2 inch.

Comment: Yes i understand that i will need to compensate for the added rubber piece and move the bracket accordingly.

Comment: The orange screws are used pretty consistently on all 3 doors in this location, as well as the bracket that holds the spring itself.

Comment: It is probably the mount bracket for the motor that is transferring sound/vibration to the structure, not the track brackets. Make sure the drive screw or chain and the wheels on the door are lubricated well.

Answer (score 2):

When the door is up on the track there is weight on it but when the door is down only the weight of the track is at that location.

Those vibration isolators are really made for compression. I use them on some motor loads they are nothing more than 2 bolts with a cast rubber holding them together. There would need to be some kind of safety device for when the rubber fails so your door and track are not damaged when they break.